# cells in collection view are not visible

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Here is the code of the collection view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    [_teamsCollection registerClass:[MWTeamCollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

}
#pragma mark data source and delegate methods of collection view
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 10;
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MWTeamCollectionCell *cell = [_teamsCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = (MWTeamCollectionCell*)[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.teamName.text = @"team name";
    return cell;
}
```

When I debug the line `return cell;`, I get proper log, but I do not see the cells.

```
(gdb) po cell
<MWTeamCollectionCell: 0x72aff80; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 50 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x72b0090>>
(gdb) po cell
<MWTeamCollectionCell: 0x72b08e0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (67.5 0; 50 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x72b0970>>
(gdb) po cell
<MWTeamCollectionCell: 0x8aad380; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (135 0; 50 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x8a72d20>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't need to register class like UITabeView, try this:

```
[yourCollection registerClass:[MWTeamCollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellName"];
```

And then

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MWTeamCollectionCell *cell = [yourCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellName" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //Setting some thing here

    return cell;

}
```

That's enough, remember MWTeamCollectionCell:UICollectionViewCell and customize in (id)init in MWTeamCollectionCell.m(init your teamName label)

And UICollectionView work only with iOS6, if you try iOS5,nothing display

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are allocating a UITableViewCell instead of a UICollectionViewCell.

Also, depending on how you implemented your custom collection cell, ensure the nib has been decoded (loaded) properly. I suggest using a UICollectionViewCell first to verify your outlets and identifier name in interface builder are correct.

Comment: How do I do that: verify your outlets and identifier name in interface builder are correct?

Comment: You are right :) I did allocated UITableViewCell. 
Here is my new code (it still doesn't work :( )
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    MWTeamCollectionCell *cell = [_teamsCollection dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.teamName.text = @"team name";
    return cell;
}

Answer (score 0):

Replacing this line

```
[yourCollection registerClass:[MWTeamCollectionCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellName"];
```

With below working lines

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MWTeamCollectionCell" bundle:nil];    
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CellName"];
```

worked well for me.